# How do I stop a timer from activating if there is speech recognized?

Tags: c#, timer, speech-recognition

I have a problem that I am having trouble resolving. Every two seconds a timer_elapsed event fires and moves to the next item in a group of choices. While this is happening, the application is waiting to hear a command using the Microsoft.Speech speech recognition libraries. When it hears that command it is supposed to move to the next group of choices. Sometimes though, the command comes exactly when the timer elapses and because the speech recognition is moving asynchronously the speechrecogonized event will move the choices to the next group while the timer will move within its group.

To control the movement through groups, I have created a set of modes. The timer will call a function based on the current mode. Speech controls what mode you're in and is changed within the speechrecognized event. I have tried putting the timer.stop() at the very beginning of the speechrecognized event but that is useless. They are called together at the same time quite often.

I am a beginning to average programmer. I understand the concepts behind threads but don't really have much experience working with them.
Thank you.

```
    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(stopTimer)return;
        if (mode == Mode.Group1)
        {
            displayGroup1();
        }
        else if (mode == Mode.Group2)
        {
            displayGroup2();
        }
        else if (mode == Mode.Group3)
        {
            displayGroup3();
        }

    }




    void sre_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopTimer=false;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void sre_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopTimer=true;
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        stopTimer=true;
        if (e.Result.Text == "yes")
        {
               changeMode();
        }
    }
```

I have pasted above the most relevant code sections and cleaned out unnecessary details.

Comment: The speechrecognized event is most likely only fired after a speech pattern has been processed. I assume that you want the timer to stop already at the time the person starts speaking. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: If my assumption in my former comment is correct, then look into the [SpeechRecognitionEngine.SpeechDetected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechdetected.aspx) event.

Comment: We tried that before. It does happen a bit less often but it still happens especially when we're trying to test it very near to when the time will elapse.

Comment: Note that your audio input feed might introduce a delay (depending on the underlying software/drivers, etc...) of a few milliseconds. You cannot magically get rid of that (unless you have a time machine that can look a few milliseconds into the future...). Your approach when the event fires should be either: (A) Stop timer. Check if the timer callback is currently executing. If it does, stop the execution of the timer callback (and perhaps you need to rollback any changes it tried to make). Or (B) Stop timer. Check if timer callback is currently executing. If it does, ignore the speech event.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I should check if the timer event is currently running when I detect speech. If it is, dump the speech input. The only thing I found about timer callbacks is in System.threading.timers. Any similar solution for system.timers?

Comment: I think you confuse something. The timer object itself does not know whether the timer callback is still executing, or wether it already finished. You will need to employ a boolean flag for example, which is set in your timer callback, and tested in your speech event handler. (I always talk about timer callbacks. It is bad habit. Of course i mean "your timer event handler" :) )

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. I actually tried that before but the other way around. I created a boolean value and named it stopTimer. When speech is detected, it would set this to true and then reset it to false in the end. In the timer_elapsed, I would check the stopTimer value and if it is true, I would just stop the timer and handle the speech recognition event. So in my case, I dump the timer event. Unfortunately, this did not fully resolve the issue. Sometimes the timer event is fired before speech gets a chance to change it.

Comment: Okay, then i would suggest you include the relevant parts of your code in your question. Otherwise, our discussion here devolves into "something, something, blind guess, blind guess..."

Comment: I posted my answer. Unfortunately, i can't test it since i don't have the means to do so here (no Microsoft Speech, no Visual Studio). If you have trouble with the code or the understanding of it, please leave a comment below of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intro - what is it all about**

In the following i will explain a basic solution which will attempt to implement a behavior (you might also call it a rule) for the case that *Timer.Elapsed* events overlap with incoming speech events.

The behaviour demonstrated here can be briefly explained as follows:

- While an *Timer.Elapsed* event is executed, any incoming speech events should be ignored.
- When a speech event occurs and no *Timer.Elapsed* events are executed, stop the timer and handle the speech event. After handling the speech event, restart the timer.

For the following explanation of the code, i assume the reader has an understanding of Microsoft Speech's [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) class and its events.

**The code and how it works**

1. The [SpeechDetected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechdetected.aspx) event handler stops the timer. It also checks, if the *Timer.Elapsed* event handler is currently executing (via *isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting*) - if it does, the *ignoreSpeechInput* flag will be set to *true*, indicating that the processed audio data should be ignored.
   (The lock i will explain in section 5.)

   ```
   void sre_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
   {
       lock (_lockObj)
       {
           timer.Enabled = false;

           //
           // Given the the explanation above, i should write the code for
           // setting of the ignoreSpeechInput flag like this:
           //   ignoreSpeechInput = isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting ? true : false;
           //
           // But obviously that is the same as writing the following...
           //
           ignoreSpeechInput = isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting;
       }
   }
   ```
2. The [SpeechRecognized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechrecognized.aspx) event handler decides based on the *ignoreSpeechInput* flag, whether the speech input should be ignored or not. It also restarts the timer (which was stopped in the *SpeechDetected* handler above.

   ```
   private void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (!ignoreSpeechInput)
       {
           if (e.Result.Text == "yes")
               changeMode();
       }

       timer.Enabled = true;
   }
   ```
3. Similar to the *SpeechRecognized* handler, the handler for the [SpeechRecognitionRejected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechrecognitionrejected.aspx) event also needs to restart the timer.

   ```
   void sre_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
   {
       timer.Enabled = true;
   }
   ```
4. Beside its main functionality, the [Timer.Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) event handler will also have to set *isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting* accordingly to indicate whether it is executing or whether is finished (i.e., not executing).
   You will also note that it explicitly test for *Timer.Enabled*. The reason for doing so is that there is a possibility that when *Timer.Enabled* is set back to *false* one or more Elapsed events are still queued for execution on a ThreadPool thread and which would be executed after *Timer.Enabled* has been set to *false* (although i don't really *believe* that this will happen with your timer interval of 2 seconds).

   The *try-finally* simply ensures that *isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting* will be set to false, even if the code in this method throws an exception.

   ```
   void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       lock (_lockObj)
       {
           if (!timer.Enabled)
               return;

           isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting = true;
       }

       try
       {
           if (mode == Mode.Group1)
               displayGroup1();
           else if (mode == Mode.Group2)
               displayGroup2();
           else if (mode == Mode.Group3)
               displayGroup3();
       }
       finally
       {
           isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting = false;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Why is this `lock(_lockObj)` being used?
   Without that lock your software could run into the following scenario:

   1. *sre_SpeechDetected* is invoked, executing on thread **A**. More or less at the same time, *timer_Elapsed* is invoked, executing on thread **B**.
   2. *timer_Elapsed* on thread **B** sees that *Timer.Enabled* is *true*.
   3. A few ticks (CPU clock cycles) later, *sre_SpeechDetected* on thread **A** sets *Timer.Enabled* to *false*, and it also executes `ignoreSpeechInput = isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting;`. *isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting* is *false* at that point in time, thus *ignoreSpeechInput* becomes *false*, too.
   4. Again a few ticks later, *timer_Elapsed* on thread **B** sets *isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting* to *true*.
   5. Now the speech event handlers **incorrectly** believe that no Timer.Elapsed handler is executing (because of *ignoreSpeechInput == false*).
      The execution sequence illustrated in points 1. to 4. is called a "Race Condition", and is usually very difficult to debug, as the occurrence of such bugs often depend on a complex combination of certain characteristics of the CPU, overall system load,the behavior of OS and other software running on the system, the weather on that particular day, etc... Of course, this type of bug never occurs on the development and test systems, only on computers of customers ;-)
6. Summary of the variables used in the code and their default values (declared as private class members):

   ```
   private readonly object _lockObj = new object();
   private bool isTimerElapsedHandlerExecuting = false;
   private bool ignoreSpeechInput = false;

   private System.Timer timer = ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you soo much for this. The explanations really helped me understand what you were doing. The solution worked perfectly and so far I am unable to reproduce the problem. I will make sure to read up more on this topic. My little Googling into it is leading me to books on operating systems for some reason. I will have to look more into it.